# Use a variable to define PHP function parameters

Tags: php, function

Here's my problem, I'd like to have a string that would define my function parameters like this :

```
 function blabla($param1, $param2){
  my cool code . $param1 . $param2;
 }

 $params = 'param1, param2';
 blabla($params);
```

The problem is that when I do this, he uses the string 'param1, param2' as ONE arguments instead of TWO like i'd want 2

Comment: not how php works, sir. Aside that, functions don't begin with $. you may be better off expecting an array as your function argument and pass array('param1', 'param2')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you are wanting to do it, you can't.  However, look in to [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) as it may solve what you are trying to do.  Demonstration follows:

```
function blabla($param1, $param2){
  echo "my cool code $param1 $param2";
}

$params = 'does,work';
call_user_func_array('blabla', explode(',', $params));
```

Comment: You're the best, in fact, it's exactly what I wanted to do eheh, thx alot, what is call_user_func_array doing exactly ?

Comment: @YannChabot What it does is pass parameters to the function like you want.  The array is an indexed array that holds them, and can pass as many parameters as the function allows.

Answer (score 3):

That's a very backwards thing to want to do, but you'd probably do it by exploding your string into an array of values, and using `call_user_func_array` to pass those values as the parameters to the function.

```
function blah($x, $y) {
  echo "x: $x, y: $x";
}

$xy = "4, 5";

$params = explode(", ", $xy);

# Just like calling blah("4", "5");
call_user_func_array('blah', $params);
```

I'll warn you again however that you've probably chosen the wrong solution to whatever your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

use `explode()` php function

```
function blabla($param){
  $params = explode(',', $param);
  $param1 = $params[0];
  $param2 = $params[1]; 
 }

 $params = 'param1, param2';
 blabla($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is interpreting this as one argument because you have specified a single string, which just happens to include a comma; just something to bear in mind for the future.

Comment: I know ! I understood the problem, just didnt knew how to make PHP understanding that this string was not 'Hey, yo' but '"hey","yo"'

Answer (score 0):

Something very simple is:

```
function blabla($param1, $param2){
  my_cool_code . $param1 . $param2;
}

blabla($param1, $param2);
```

First, a function name must not have a '$'. Secondly, you have only 2 params, you can pass both params through the function, like above.

The code is now good to use :)